# How to set routing for two Separated projects with Angular and Express?

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack

I'm trying to separate projects frontend and backend.
One is built with angular-cli, other is built with express.

I know I should load the index.html in dist folder like, `app.use(express.static('../../frontend/dist'));`

If I access to mydomain.com, then it works fine.
However, when I try to access mydomain.com/signin on the browser address bar with typing, then it shows `can not get /signin`.

I guess it is because I made a mistake in the process that I was separating front and backend projects.

I did like below, but I think I need to do something to solve this issue.
I thought `app.use(express.static('../../frontend/dist'));` is enough to route, but it couldn't set routing.

I think this one is not for my case.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');     // I split it into two projects, how can I render it?
});
```

For example,

```
app.get('/signin', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('something');
})
```

I think I can't render because I split it into two projects.

That's why I used this code. `app.use(express.static('../../frontend/dist'));`

How to set routing in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I solved like below.
It's because I didn't understand well.
I know it's a beginner question, but for other beginners like me, post my answer.

First, install path npm package.
`npm install path --save`

Second, add `var path = require('path');`

Third, add `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'your path/dist')));`

Finally, add

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'your path/dist/index.html'));
    });
```

It was really simple.
I hope someone get the solution in my answer. :D